# Two trigger colliders next to each other - Bug

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 colliders next to each other both calling these

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.name == "Cursor") 
    { 
        audioSource.clip = audioClip;
        audioSource.Play();
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.name == "Cursor")
    {
        audioSource.Stop();
    }
}
```

The problem is they are pretty close to each other and when I jump from one to the other the audio doesn't play. However, if I point away then come back to one of the colliders audio is working.

What could be the problem here?

Thanks

Comment: there is a race condition here. as soon as audio starts to play other one stops it. you should add some delay between them if you want to keep audio playing. unfortunately you cant wait for audio to finish playing because I think `audioSource.Play();` is fire and forget method

Answer (score 0):

Try `audioSource.PlayOneshoot(sound)` and you does not need to stop the audio it will play it once.

Comment: but I am looping the audio